# querySelectorAll for element contain specific class

Tags: javascript, dom, selectors-api

I have few divs that contain two classes such as this:

```
<div class="dateNumbers"></div>
<div class="dateNumbers {{month.year + '-' + month.monthName + '-' + 'end'}}"></div>
<div class="dateNumbers {{month.year + '-' + month.monthName + '-' + 'end'}}"></div>
<div class="dateNumbers {{month.year + '-' + month.monthName + '-' + 'end'}}"></div>
```

where `{{month.year + '-' + month.monthName + '-' + 'end'}}` for a certain month is `2018-August-end`

I want to select the divs that contain only `2018-August-end` which I store into a variable so I tried something like this

```
var dataName = `2018-August-end`; // this is dynamic but for this example I have it static

document.querySelectorAll( "." + dataName);
```

but I get this error

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on
>   'Document': '.2018-August-end' is not a valid selector.
>       at :1:10

why is that ?

Thanks

Comment: classes shouldn't start with a number, try adding a character before

Comment: Not a duplicate, but see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/which-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-names-selectors

Comment: @Mohd_PH Thanks!

Comment: @FissureKing Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Class name [dot (`.`) *selectors*](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#class-html) can't start with an unescaped digit (`2`, in your case).

The simplest solution is to just start them with a letter instead, which I strongly recommend:

Example:

```js
const datePart = "x2018-August-end";
console.log(
  document.querySelectorAll(".\\" + datePart).length
);
```

```html
<div class="dateNumbers"></div>
<div class="dateNumbers x2018-August-end"></div>
<div class="dateNumbers x2018-August-end"></div>
<div class="dateNumbers x2018-August-end"></div>
```

Alternately, you can use the [`[class~=value]` notation](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#attribute-representation), which is functionally identical (for HTML):

```
document.querySelectorAll("[class~='" + datePart + "']")
```

Example:

```js
const datePart = "2018-August-end";
console.log(
  document.querySelectorAll("[class~='" + datePart + "']").length
);
```

```html
<div class="dateNumbers"></div>
<div class="dateNumbers 2018-August-end"></div>
<div class="dateNumbers 2018-August-end"></div>
<div class="dateNumbers 2018-August-end"></div>
```

It's also possible to escape the first digit with `.` notation, but it's **painful**. (You can't just throw a backslash in front of it, as you can with some libraries like jQuery.)

Answer (score 0):

Element by tagName like this:

```
document.querySelectorAll(`svg,b,u,i,span,a,path,circle,rect,polygon,ellipse`)
```

Element by tagName and also with class:

```
document.querySelectorAll(`svg,b,u,i,span,a,path,circle,rect,polygon,ellipse,div[class~="background"]`)
```

Element by svg inner gradient stops:

```
document.querySelectorAll(`svg,defs,stop`)
```

Element by data or dataset:

```
document.querySelectorAll(`[data-target]`)
```

Element by data and ignore element that have a specific class:

```
document.querySelectorAll(`[data-target]:not([class*="background"]`)
```